# How to change windows 7 theme using external sources

Tags: windows-7, themes

I have installed a custom theme on my machine. Now I messed it up and cannot see anything when I launch any explorer window:
[image]

The mouse icon keeps on spinning when I launch any explorer window. And the desktop appearance menu when you right click on the desktop is also a part of explorer.exe. 
Now I need to know if there is any software that lets me change the theme back to normal.
I've already tried explorer++ but it doesn't have what I need.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to change the theme in such a way, but perhaps you could temporarily disable the Themes service?

If you open an administrator command prompt (Start > "cmd" > right click > *Run as Administrator*) then type the following:

```
net stop Themes
```

That should stop the Themes service and hopefully allow you to fix your problem.

Once you've reset your theme you can restart the Themes service with the following command:

```
net start Themes
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, its now back to normal. I used the theme changer in tune up utilities to change back to aero theme. Then restarted explorer from the task manager.

Comment: Did you have to stop the Themes service, or using TuneUp Utilities was the only thing needed?